# How can I transfrom Object into a Formgroup?

Tags: typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Im having trouble in converting an object to a formgroup. I have initialization of my form. And I've got surveyData, an object of the same structure,. I was wondering how to make the values of my object transform into a FormGroup

```
surveyForm: FormGroup;
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.surveyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       'surveyTitle': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
       'surveyDescription': new FormControl(null),
       'questionsDetail': this.formBuilder.array([
         this.formBuilder.group({
          'questionType': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
           'question': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
           'choices': this.formBuilder.array([])
         })
       ])
     });
     
    };
```

I would really appreciate the help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a bit of recursion. Of course if you don't like recursion you can always convert it to an iteration but for us people recursion is easier to understand sometimes.

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  const data = {
      email: 'test@email.com',
      password: 'test-password',
      address: [
        {
          street: 'Street 1',
          postCode: 1000
        },
        {
          street: null,
          postCode: null
        }
      ]
    };

    const validationSchema = {
      email: [[Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: [[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
      address: [
        {
          street: [[Validators.required]],
          postCode: [[Validators.required]]
        },
        {
          street: [[Validators.required]],
          postCode: [[Validators.required]]
        }
      ]
    };

    this.form = this.parseData(data, validationSchema) as FormGroup;

  }


  parseData(data: any, validators?: any): FormGroup | FormArray | [any, ValidatorFn[], AsyncValidatorFn[]] {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      return this.fb.array(data.map((item, index) => this.parseData(item, (validators || {})[index])));
    }
    if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null) {
      const formGroupContent = {};
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        formGroupContent[key] = this.parseData(value, (validators || {})[key]);
      }
      return this.fb.group(formGroupContent);
    }
    const [syncValidators = [], asyncValidators = []] = validators || [];
    return [data, syncValidators, asyncValidators];
  }
```

the parseData method reads the data object and depending on the value creates either a `formArray`, `formGroup` or `formControl` (but using the short syntax with and array - [value, syncValidators, asyncValidators]). Here I assume that you have the validation schemas somewhere for each individual form but if you are holding them inside the data object itself using strings or something you could create a similar function that constructs the validation schema from the schema object that you receive from the backend.

I've spend sometime with dynamic form generation and the fun part begins when you start connecting the different form element inside the template of your component because you will have to do something similar there as well. From what I remember I used different templates for the individual form element and I was passing the parent element inside the context of the template in order to be able to connect everything properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have initial data? Looks like you will. You can use angular template driven approach to map a data from object to the `ngModel` directive in the template.

```html
<form #form>
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.surveyTitle" required>
 ...
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.questionsDetail.choices">
</form>
```

```
interface IData {
   surveyTitle: string;
   questionsDetail: {
      ...
      choices: string;
   }
}

@Component({...})
export MyComponent {
   // for the reason if you need an entire form to get a status e.g dirty or access to the entire form data
   // 'form' will be available in 'ngAfterViewInit' hook
   @ViewChild('form', {static: true, read: NgForm})
   form: NgForm
   
   @Input()
   data: IData
}
```

Comment: Are keys in the object dynamic? If so, it should be another approach similarly what are you doing right now.